# curl_setopt_array throwing warning message

Tags: php, cookies, curl, syntax-error

I am trying to login into a website through cURL and have it return to me the actual page.   So far I can only get the footer of the page with the feedback link and this error:

> Warning: curl_setopt_array() [function.curl-setopt-array]: Array keys
>   must be CURLOPT constants or equivalent integer values  on line 18
>
> Loading

line 18 is the ");" at the end of the curl array

So far I've been able to figure out that if I just put in the website name with the access_token in my url from my browser I'll automatically be logged in so I'm trying to get cURL to emulate that.

```
<?php
$ckfile ='  __utma=173730677.1410450142.1370837396.1370843059.4; __utmz=173730677.1370843059.4.3.utmcsr=web.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/ou; __utma=64278953.892306882.1370766510.1370838026.4; __utmz=64278953.4.3.utmcsr=.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/signin; __utmc=64278953; __utmc=173730677; __utmb=173730677.5.10.1370843059; __utmb=64278953.1.10';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array(
    $ch,
    array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://web.com',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE=> $ckfile,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT =>'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0',
    CURLOPT_GET=> true,
    CURLOPT_REFERER => 'https://.com/signin',
    CURLOPT_GETFIELDS=>'#access_token=',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true  
    )
);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);    

echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
?>
```

Comment: my bad line 18 is the ); at the very end

Answer (score 0):

`CURLOPT_GET` and `CURLOPT_GETFIELDS` are not a valid options for cURL.  The options may exist for `POST`, but they do not for `GET`.  Just add the query string to the URL instead.

Also, make sure all the options are set to what cURL expects them to be set to.  `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` should be set to a filename, not a string of cookie values.  You want `CURLOPT_COOKIE` instead.

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://web.com?access_token=abc',
    CURLOPT_COOKIE=> $ckfile,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT =>'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0',
    CURLOPT_REFERER => 'https://web.com/signin',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true  
));
```

Please see the PHP cURL docs for all the options: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: i get the exact same result : /

Comment: Make sure you don't have any invalid cURL options.  Did you remove both `CURLOPT_GET` and `CURLOPT_GETFIELDS`?

Comment: Also, you were using `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` incorrectly.  Check my updated answer.

Comment: oh my bad i left the curl_get now i dont get an error but just a blank page with the footer links. I want to be able to see everything is my code correct? Also I just checked live http headers and it turns out im logged into like 10 different sites when I login should i set up a curl for each site?

Comment: Check the source of the page, the browser might be rendering the returned HTML data.  Hint: you forgot a `</pre>`.

Comment: Ok I'll check the source, thank you again. sorry for all the syntax mistakes still trying to learn.

Comment: It's fine.  We all start somewhere :-)

Comment: ok so I'm pretty sure now that the single webpage isn't enough and that i need to log in to a couple pages after. How do I execute multiple commands sequentially?

Comment: @user2471201: Do the multiple sites share cookies?  Just run the other cURL requests after the first one.

Comment: yeah they share cookies, so i would just do `curl_setopt_array(
 $ch,` again or do i have to use a new variable like $ch2

Comment: @user2471201: You did `curl_close`, so you need to re-call `curl_init` and `curl_setopt_array`.  You can re-use `$ch` if you want.